# SELECT multiple times same column returns duplicated

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following tables:

`table1`:

```
id | idFirst | idLast | value
1  |    1    |   2    |  0
2  |    4    |   5    |  0
3  |    6    |   8    |  1
```

`table1.idFirst` and `table1.idLast` are `FK` pointing to `table2.id`

`table2`:

```
id | level
1  | 123
2  | 124
3  | 125
4  | 126
5  | 127
6  | 128
7  | 129
8  | 130
```

I want to perform a query that returns `table2.level` of all the registers on `table1` where `table1.value==0`. My approach was the following:

```
SELECT T1.id
(SELECT T2.level WHERE T1.idFirst=T2.id) AS x1,
(SELECT T2.level WHERE T1.idLast=T2.id) AS x2
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON T1.idFirst=T2.id OR T1.idLast=T2.id
WHERE table1.value=0
GROUP BY T1.id
ORDER BY T1.id ASC;
```

The result of this query has the following structure:

[image]

The problem with this is that the `GROUP BY` is not correctly grouping the registers x1 and x2, and therefore the result is null for x1 while the column x2 has correct values. If I delete the `GROUP BY` statement, all the expected registers are obtained but as they are not groupped, as can be seen bellow:

[image]

Therefore, my question is: how can I perform this query without losing all the registers of one of the columns?

Comment: What is your expected output for your sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must join `table1` to 2 copies of `table2`:

```
select t1.id, 
       t21.level x1,
       t22.level x2
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t21 on t21.id = t1.idFirst
inner join table2 t22 on t22.id = t1.idLast
where t1.value = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/psgQ7oj5ra6FFrnCQoeeCK/0).
Results:

```
| id  | x1  | x2  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 123 | 124 |
| 2   | 126 | 127 |
```